# Encoding video stream by http protocol using ffmpeg library

Tags: http, video, ffmpeg, encode

I'm trying to encode video files, that users upload on my server.
I interpretate file as stream, incoming on my server by http protocol and use ffmpeg for realtime file encoding, while upload procedure executes.

When source file have `.avi` format, I have successful encoding result, but on `.mp4` format appears error:

```
---------------------
[buffer @ 0000000000308380] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0000000000308380] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
---------------------
```

I think this might be because .mp4 contains `"moov atom"` data in the end of file. 
I think so because when I processing file by `"-movflags faststart"` command before encoding, I also have successful result.

That is the command i using now:

```
ffmpeg -i http://myhost.com/app/video/video2.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800K -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128K -ar 44100 -ac 2 -y c:/watch-and-get/video/video5.mp4
```

Can I resolve this problem and encode multiple video formats as a stream without any excess steps?

Comment: Better suited for SuperUser, really. Might be answered over there already: http://superuser.com/questions/546560/ffmpeg-unable-to-parse-option-value-1-as-pixel-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are running an old version of ffmpeg. this problem was fixed.

`-pix_fmt` is pixel format and its value should be an integer.(ffmpeg somehow takes this value as -1, i am not sure why. hence u get that error. but updating would solve this problem)

extra info : run `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` to see the all the available pixel formats.

download the latest version.
i would recommend installing the latest version from a binary as it is much simpler. i have answered about the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709115/how-to-load-correct-libavcodec-so-shared-library-version-53/24797288#24797288)