# Singler line FFMPEG cmd to Merge Video /Audio and retain both audios

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a project that requires merging of a video file with another audio file. The  expected out put is an video file that will have both the audio from actual video and the merged audio file. The length of the output video file will be same to the size of the actual video file.

Is there a single line FFMPEG  command to achieve this using copy and -map parameters ?

The video form I will be using is either flv or mp4
And the audio file format will be mp3

Answer (score 61):

There can be achieved without using map also.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 output.mp4`

In case you want the output.mp4 to stop as soon as one of the input stops (audio/video)
then use

`-shortest`

For example: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -shortest output.mp4`

This will make sure that the output stops as and when any one of the inputs is completed.

Since you have asked that you want to do it with map. this is how you do it:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest output.mp4`

Now, since you want to retain the audio of the video file, consider you want to merge `audio.mp3` and `video.mp4`. These are the steps:

1. Extract audio from the video.mp4

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 1.mp3`

2. Merge both audio.mp3 and 1.mp3

`ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i 1.mp3  -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 audiofinal.mp3`

3. Remove the audio from video.mp4 (this step is not required. but just to do it properly)

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -an videofinal.mp4`

4. Now merge audiofinal.mp3 and videofinal.mp4

`ffmpeg  -i videofinal.mp4 -i audiofinal.mp3 -shortest final.mp4`

**note:** in the latest version of ffmpeg it will only prompt you to use '-strict -2' in case it does then use this:

`ffmpeg  -i videofinal.mp4 -i audiofinal.mp3 -shortest -strict -2 final.mp4`

hope this helps.

Comment: yes just change the output format to .flv and u are good to go

Comment: I tried the 2nd example of yours but the output video did not pick up the audio from the mp3 file. The output mp4 is just the same like the input mp4 file. Should that be some thing wrong with my FFMPEG installation ,If you are very sure about this CMD then I can try it on a different server. Please confirm.Thanks again.

Comment: yes very sure. i tried it once again. i am on ffmpeg version 2.2.4 (2000-2014). if you are having trouble with the installation check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709115/how-to-load-correct-libavcodec-so-shared-library-version-53/24797288#24797288) installing through pre compiled binaries is the best way to install.

Comment: This is crazy, I tried the same on a different server(linux) that has the same version of FFMPEG as yours. But this time the output video picked up the sound from the mp3 file and lost the original sound in the video file. I wanted the output to keep both the video sound and the audio sound. Surprised why FFMPEG would behave so different in different installations.

Comment: Ohh even I am clueless why that happened. May be u haven't installed all the codecs . That could be a possibility.

Comment: Rajath one last help, Can you please send me your ffmpeg configuration (ffmpeg -version). Below given is my configuration :configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-libtheora --enable-avfilter --enable-libtheora --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid

Comment: not a problem. `configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect` u are on which OS?

Comment: hello @RajathKumarM.P i am also using this command but my .wav file is not merging with .mp4

Comment: Below command is merging audio and video properly in android.. 
**ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/input_video.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/input_audio.mp3 -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -strict -2 -b:a 16k -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest -f mp4 -r 2 /storage/emulated/0/output_video.mp4** 

           _Its giving me same inputted video file (i.e. without merging with inputted audio) If I dont use -map 0:0 -map 1:0_

Comment: @Rajath i want to merge video and audio , i used this command for merging but i have a problem that when i merge whats app video and mp3 file then it is done but when i record video and then this video merge to mp3 file then it provide success result but its not merged. what is the problem behind that?

Comment: Step #2, you may need to change it to`ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame audiofinal.mp3` to prevent longest audio is truncated.

Answer (score 16):

### You can not do that using one cmd.

---

**1. Get the audio from video file, the audio file name is *a.mp3***

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 a.mp3
```

**2. Merge two audio files(audio.mp3+a.mp3=audiofinal.mp3)**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i audio.mp3 -i a.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 audiofinal.mp3
```

**3. Merge video file and audio file(video.mp4+audiofinal.mp3=output.mp4)**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i audiofinal.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -y output.mp4
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think extracting the audio from the video is necessary. We can just use `-filter_complex amix` to merge both audios:

`ffmpeg -i videowithaudio.mp4 -i audiotooverlay.mp3 -filter_complex amix -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a -shortest videowithbothaudios.mp4`

`-filter_complex amix` overlays the audio from the first input file on top of audio in the second input file.

`-map 0:v` video stream of the first input file.

`-map 0:a` audio stream of the first input file.

`-map 1:a` audio stream of the second input file.

`-shortest` the length of the output is the length of the shortest input

Answer (score 4):

Use case:

- add music to your background
- you rendered a video, but muted some part of it, so you don't want to render it again(coz it's too long), instead you render only audio track(fast) and wanna merge it with original video.

**Assuming**

- you have your video with you speech (*or just audio track, whatever*)
- your *music_file* is not loud. Otherwise, you will not hear yourself D:

---

Steps:

1) **Extract audio from the video**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 1.mp3
```

test.mp4 - your file

2) **Merge both audio.mp3 and 1.mp3**

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 audiofinal.mp3
```

audiofinal.mp3 - audio with music

3) **Delete audio from original**

```
ffmpeg -i example.mkv -c copy -an example-nosound.mkv
```

example-nosound.mkv - your video without audio

4) **Merge with proper audio**

```
ffmpeg -i audiofinal.mp3 -i example-nosound.wmv -c:v copy -vcodec copy final.wmv
```

final.wmv - your perfect video.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org):

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 1 -q:v 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:0 -map 1:0
```

Comment: i want to merge video and audio , i used this command for merging but i have a problem that when i merge whats app video and mp3 file then it is done but when i record video and then this video merge to mp3 file then it provide success result but its not merged. what is the problem behind that?

Answer (score -1):

First remove the sound from video if you are not able to merge video and audio by using this command:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -an videofinal.mp4

Comment: This is not a solution and will re-encode the video.

Comment: ok, I was not able to merge my Audio/Video with above given commands. when first i run the command to remove the audio from video and then use the merge command. It fixed my problem. May be it could be helpful for others.