# Android ffmpeg unable to merge audio(.wav file) with video(.mp4 file)

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

i am working on FFMPEG library,in which i am merging audio (.wav file) with video (.mp4 file) , for that iam using following command here:

```
*String commandStr=    "ffmpeg,-y,-i,mnt/sdcard/Scatta/Scattatemp.mp4,-i,/storage/emulated/0/MicDroid/recordings/video.wav ,-strict,experimental,-map,0:0,-map,1:0,-vcodec,mpeg4,-vb,15496k,-ab,128k,-ac,2,-ar,22050,-shortest,mnt/sdcard/Scatta/mergedFile.mp4";
```

for that i am using following code,but my command is not working, i am getting Commandvalidation failed exception

```
GeneralUtils.deleteFileUtil(workFolder + "/vk.log");

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)_act.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK"); 
        Log.d("Prefs.TAG", "Acquire wake lock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
String commandStr=  "ffmpeg,-y,-i,mnt/sdcard/Scatta/Scattatemp.mp4,-i,/storage/emulated/0/MicDroid/recordings/video.wav ,-strict,experimental,-map,0:0,-map,1:0,-vcodec,mpeg4,-vb,15496k,-ab,128k,-ac,2,-ar,22050,-shortest,mnt/sdcard/Scatta/mergedFile.mp4"   ;

LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
        try {

            vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());
            GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);

        } catch (CommandValidationException e) {
            Log.e("Prefs.TAG", "vk run exeption.", e);
            commandValidationFailedFlag = true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e("Prefs.TAG", "vk run exeption.", e);
        }
        finally {
            if (wakeLock.isHeld())
                wakeLock.release();
            else{
                Log.i("Prefs.TAG", "Wake lock is already released, doing nothing");
            }
        }
        Log.i("Prefs.TAG", "doInBackground finished");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(".exception"+e.toString());
    }
```

i am getting following exception

```
 04-08 10:00:38.891: D/ffmpeg4android(7781): deleteing: /data/data/org.scatta.androidclient/files//vk.log isdeleted: false
 04-08 10:00:38.891: D/Prefs.TAG(7781): Acquire wake lock
 04-08 10:00:38.896: I/System.out(7781): <--- command strffmpeg -i  mnt/sdcard/Scatta/Scattatemp.mp4 -i    /storage/emulated/0/MicDroid/recordings/video.wav -acodec copy mnt/sdcard/Scatta/mergedFile.mp4
 04-08 10:00:38.896: E/ffmpeg4android(7781): Command validation failed.
 04-08 10:00:38.896: E/ffmpeg4android(7781): Check if input file exists: /storage/emulated/0/MicDroid/recordings/video.wav
    04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781): vk run exeption.
  04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781): com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.CommandValidationException
    04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):  at com.netcompss.loader.LoadJNI.run(LoadJNI.java:26)
  04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):    at com.scatta.androidclient.ui.PlaybackScreen$TranscdingBackground.doInBackground(PlaybackScreen.java:159)
   04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):   at com.scatta.androidclient.ui.PlaybackScreen$TranscdingBackground.doInBackground(PlaybackScreen.java:1)
   04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
  04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
  04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 04-08 10:00:38.896: E/Prefs.TAG(7781):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Hello navya i thing problem in your command

Comment: @AnandMakwana yes sir..but  i am not getting where i am doing wrong

Comment: "Check if input file exists: /storage/emulated/0/MicDroid/recordings/video.wav"

Comment: (You forgot to write @slhck) You can check if the file exists using Java. Why do you assume the file is there? Are you sure that there is a `video.wav` at the location you specify?

Answer (score 0):

-You can see there is error calling check your file so first of all check your **File** realy exist or not that you are trying to merge.

Another thing is Check your **Command**

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804928/singler-line-ffmpeg-cmd-to-merge-video-audio-and-retain-both-audios)

-Above is the link related your answer thanks!